# Multiple inputs in one command

Tags: shell-script, grep, variable

I've got something like this:

```
Error_code=1; num=5;
Error_code=2; num=7;
Error_code=3; num=9;
Error_code=1; num=2;
Error_code=2; num=5;
```

. . .

And a lot of error codes (about 100). Suppose the file is called `performance.log`

How can I use one command? Each time the error code is different.  I have something like this:

```
grep -i "error_code=$x;" performance.log | \
   awk -F";" '{print $2}' > $x_error_code.txt
```

So each time, the variable `x` is a new value defined from the error code, and when the error codes finish, the script will finish.

Comment: What is wrong with your command? Your commands seems to work fine. If you apply i.e `x=2` before grep, your command will print `num=7` and `num=5`. You need to double quote `> "$x_error_code.txt"`

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou i want the value of x to be automatic not manual

Comment: I've looked through your question couple times but still not clear what you're trying to achieve. You want to basically step from 1 to 100 and grep each time ? Please clarify what you are trying to achieve, maybe post an example of desired output. Are you trying to sort the lines based on error code ?

Comment: @Serg i have multiple error_code each one got num and when that same error happen it register a new num so i want to grep many patterns but each pattern goes to a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `awk` script could do all this. This can also be done with pure Bourne shell script, like this one below:

```
grep -E -o '[[:digit:]]+; num=[^;]+' performance.log \
| while IFS="; " read n num; do
    echo "$num" >> "${n}_error_code.txt"
done
```

The `grep` part extracts the substring "`EEE; num=NNN`" from your lines "`Error_code=EEE; num=NNN;`". The while loop reads `EEE` and `num=NNN` and writes the latter in `EEE_error_code.txt`

If you are interested in just one particular error code (EEE below), you can change the `grep` command to:

```
grep -E -o '\<EEE; num=[^;]+' performance.log | while ...
```

If you are interested in a small set of error codes (EEE1...EEEn below), you can change the `grep` command to:

```
grep -E -o '\<(EEE1|EEE2|...|EEEn); num=[^;]+' performance.log | while ...
```

Comment: And if i dont want the whole list of error code i just want some of them like a file contain a  predefined some error codes what should i replace the [[:digit:]]

Comment: You may pre-filter the lines with another `grep -f` which takes a file of patterns in argument

Comment: Please be patient with me and tell me an example which contains a file like define.txt inside is 1 and 2 without the 3 

Comment: It's up to you to state clearly in your question above what kind of file you have in the first place, and we will answer accordingly if we can.

Comment: You gave me an answer to print all the error codes now i want to learn if i can define some of them and pass it as a variable because some times i want all the errors and some time i need to filter it by editing just one file to add or remove an error code thank you for your help

Comment: I have updated my answer. If that's not enough, please ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n "/Error_code=$x/s/^[^ ]* //p" > $x_error_code.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with awk only.

This one will scan the file and generate one file per error type

```
$ ex="";awk -F"[;=]" -v ex=$ex '{a[$2]=a[$2] "\n" $3"="$4}END{for (k in a) if (k!~ex || ex=="") print a[k] >k"error_code.txt"}' performance.log
```

If you want to "exclude" some errors you can adjust the value of shell variable ex accordingly like `ex="2|3"` (exclude 2 or 3)

Test:

```
$ echo "$c"
Error_code=1; num=5;
Error_code=2; num=7;
Error_code=3; num=9;
Error_code=1; num=2;
Error_code=22; num=5;

$ ex="";echo "$c" |awk -F"[;=]" -v ex=$ex '{a[$2]=a[$2] "\n" $3"="$4}END{for (k in a) if (k!~ex || ex=="") print a[k],k}'
 num=5
 num=2 1

 num=7 2

 num=9 3

 num=5 22

$ ex="22|1";echo "$c" |awk -F"[;=]" -v ex=$ex '{a[$2]=a[$2] "\n" $3"="$4}END{for (k in a) if (k!~ex || ex=="") print a[k],k}'

 num=7 2

 num=9 3
```

On the other hand , if you want to match specific patterns instead of excluding patterns you can do it like:

```
$ inc="1";awk -F"[;=]" -v inc=$inc '{a[$2]=a[$2] "\n" $3"="$4}END{for (k in a) if (k~inc || inc=="") print a[k] >k"error_code.txt"}' performance.log
```

Apply to var `inc` (include) the error codes you want to print or leave it empty to include all errors. (`inc=""`)